# Android Studio Unresolved Reference R in generated Fragment file

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am using fragments in my android project. Whenever I insert a second fragment in my navigation xml and connect the first to the second, I get an error. In the automatically generated FragmentDirections file I get an unresolved reference R. Unfortunately I can't find the error. If I remove the connection in the nav xml, the app starts without errors

this is the error...

```
e: path\ui\RubrikFragmentDirections.kt: (3, 8): Unresolved reference: R
```

This is the code of the autogenerated file....

```
import R
import androidx.navigation.ActionOnlyNavDirections
import androidx.navigation.NavDirections

public class RubrikFragmentDirections private constructor() {
  public companion object {
    public fun actionRubrikFragmentToOverviewFragment(): NavDirections =
        ActionOnlyNavDirections(R.id.action_rubrikFragment_to_overviewFragment)
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using? Have you updated to the latest?

Comment: Have you tried the old reliable invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: i use implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

Comment: try importing R with the full package name import com.example.projectname.R

Comment: that didn't solve the problem either